# Why my navigation controller back to my root view controller which stay before my tab bar ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3

Here is my example storyboard.

[image]

and my simulator shows

[image]

after clicking the button it goes to this page.

[image]

In this view controller when I click in button it goes to last view controller

[image]

in last view controller when I clicking the back navigation button it back me to this page.

[image]

but I want to back in this page

[image]

So how can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried on actual device ?

Comment: no.only run on simulator.

Comment: I have done same as you show above and I think you should try at least once on device.